# R Shiny Leaflet: Setting zoomDelta and zoomSnap

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet, zooming

Thank you in advance for your help.

I'm needing to change the granularity with which the zoom button (+/-) controls use in a leaflet map in R Shiny. This is probably a very easy thing to do with you are familiar with JS, but, I am not, so I need some help. I've seen a similar question asked [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266566/dynamic-leaflet-scale-zoom-bounds-in-r-shiny-applications), but no answers.

I see that:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    zoomDelta: 0.25,
    zoomSnap: 0
});
```

is the way to do this in JS.

I've tried the following (very basic version of my attempts):

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
      ) %>%
      onRender("function(el, x){var map = L.map('map', {zoomDelta: 0.25, zoomSnap: 0});}")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and this:

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(options = leafletOptions(zoomSnap = 0.01, 
                                     zoomDelta = 0.01
    )) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
      ) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What is the desired outcome? Your 2nd example seems to work.

Comment: The second option also works for me.

Comment: `zoomSnap` appears to be effective